# Using a SVG file for a background for a Windows Store app (Metro)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I have a simple Windows Store app and i'd like to use a SVG image for the background. I've created one using Inkscape and added it to the Assets folder and checked it's set to Content.

For the XAML i have the following;

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Background.svg"/>
    </Grid.Background>

</Grid>
```

Nothing is being displayed, Am i doing something wrong or is not possible to use an SVG file?

Answer (score 4):

Not directly (see [Image File Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868203.aspx#Image_file_formats)). There are however converters and other controls that would enable you to leverage SVG assets.  A number of them convert the vector SVG format to the vector XAML format.

A Bing search for me yield the following (and more).  Do note, however, these are not specifically Windows 8 focused and there are some XAML dialect differences from WPF and Silverlight. I've not used them specifically with Windows 8, so this is not an endorsemnent, but just a few options worth looking into.

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (includes a XAML export option)

[SVGImage Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92434/SVGImage-Control)

[SharpVectors](http://sharpvectors.codeplex.com/)

[ViewerSvg](http://www.ab4d-graphics.com/ViewerSvg.aspx)